# Does Chrome support Brotli? (Accept-Encoding does not contain br)

Tags: google-chrome, http-accept-encoding, brotli

`Can I use` [page](http://caniuse.com/#search=brotli) says that Chrome supports brotli for some time now. I would think that the `Accept-Encoding` string would be like this:

```
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
```

But I checked on a request to StackOverflow e.g. and it does not contain `brotli`:

```
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
```

I suppose most web servers won't really return you `brotli` if it's not in `Accept-Encoding`, so it's kind of partially supported only it seems.

Is it going to be added later or there is some trick I don't know of?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## Brotli only works over HTTPS

There are many blog posts about this if you Google it. Here's one:

https://samsaffron.com/archive/2016/06/15/the-current-state-of-brotli-compression

> **Brotli is HTTPS only**
>
> If you visit a site over HTTP your browser will not accept the br
> encoding. The reasoning for this is documented at the end of the
> chromium issue.

The Chromium issue linked is here:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=452335

## StackOverflow can be accessed on a non-HTTPS connection

Make sure you are going to https://stackoverflow.com instead of http://stackoverflow.com

*EDIT: StackOverflow can no longer be accessed on non HTTPS connection.*