# HTML file containing precompressed Brotli not encoding by Google server

Tags: html, web, google-cloud-platform, compression, brotli

I'm hosting a single page static website on Google cloud and I'm trying to implement text-compression on my `index.html` file.

What I've done so far was to copy all my minified html code from `index.html` and convert it to Brotli code using [an online converter](https://www.multiutil.com/text-to-brotli-compress/) and then saving the Brotli code as `index2.html` in my bucket. Finally I set the `Content-encoding` meta value of `index2.html` to `br`.

How ever, despite my expectation, I only see a blank page in Chrome and "Content Encoding Error" in Firefox when i go to the `www.mysite.com/index2.html` address.

I also did the same procedure with gzip compression and setting the `content-encoding` to `gzip` but the results were the same. I used the [following](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/transcoding) instructions by Google but it doesn't seem very comprehensive.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I am using HTTPS with a valid SSL. I also ckecked in my browser, and the server sent a header that includes the gzip and br in the `content-encoding` field.

Comment: Normally the web server handles compression transparently for you. You don't have to compress the files yourself. Could you check the content-encoding in the response header when accessing index.html?

Comment: @jkoch Apparently google cloud isn't doing any compression by itself since the size of the file doesn't change if I only suffice to set a content-encoding.
I checked and index.html has no content-encoding in response header. It just has a 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' in the request header. I didn't compress anything in index.html. I made index2.html temporarily just to make a practice compression first and then work my way to the real index.html.

Answer (score 1):

It almost (!) works for me but **not** how I expect it to and I'm unclear why.

I have a (JPEG) file `${IMAGE}` in a bucket that's hosting a website.

1. Copy the image locally
2. `brotli` it
3. Copy the `brotli`'d image back to the bucket
4. Set its metadata
5. Browse it.

```sh
gsutil cp gs://${BUCKET}/images/${IMAGE} ${PWD}

brotli ${IMAGE} --output=brotli.jpg

gsutil cp brotli.jpg gs://${BUCKET}/images

gsutil setmeta \
  -h "Content-Type:image/jpeg" \
  -h "Content-Encoding:br" \
  gs://${BUCKET}/images/brotli.jpg

gsutil stat gs://${BUCKET}/images/brotli.jpg 
    Content-Encoding:       br
    Content-Type:           image/jpeg
```

If I browse the site directly in Chrome, it fails (canceled) no response code:

`ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED`

If I browse the GCS public URL, it works (200):

[https://storage.googleapis.com/${BUCKET}/images/brotli.jpg](https://storage.googleapis.com/$%7BBUCKET%7D/images/brotli.jpg)

And:

[https://storage.cloud.google.com/${BUCKET}/images/brotli.jpg](https://storage.cloud.google.com/$%7BBUCKET%7D/images/brotli.jpg)

If I use `gzip` rather than `brotli`, both work as expected.

For some reason, I'm unable to browse a brotli compressed file as part of the static site even though it's definitively present and I can browse the URL via other means.

Comment: I'm doing the exact same procedure for a HTML file. I Brotli the text inside html and save it as a html file, upload it into my bucket, and set the metadata, but I'm not able to browse it.

Comment: It may be worth raising on Goggle's public [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Comment: Aha! https://stackoverflow.com/a/40782162/609290

Comment: I noticed today that Chrome DevTools showed the request to a brotli-encoding file doesn't include `Accept-Encoding: br` and a quick Google turned up that issue. Websites hosted on GCS buckets default to HTTP (in my case) explaining the issue.

Comment: No matter what browser I use results are the same. Are you suggesting it has something to do with the GCS Bucket?

Comment: I assume other browsers are requiring HTTPs similarly. This also explains why the public and authenticated URLs work as they're both HTTPs.

Comment: Yes but it still doesn't explain why Brotli compression doesn't work as expected.